How can I move uncommitted changes to, and checkout, a specific commit with Git?
I have unstaged changes (although this can be changed, just not committed) within the HEAD of my git repository, which among other things contain another git repository, and I would like to do two things:

git checkout an older commit
Bring the changes made to HEAD (namely, a directory I have created containing several files) with me into the older commit

Is a branch required here rather than using git checkout? I don't want to actually commit the changes, just bring them back for temporary usage - so creating a branch would cause the hassle of having to delete it afterwards.
Or, is there a way I can easily do this? Would the best solution without creating a branch be making a temporary directory with mktemp -d and moving the files there as an intermediate location while I git checkout the old location?

The first thing to do is just try it. The unstaged changes might just come with you when you git checkout the older commit.

If that doesn't work (i.e. if Git positively refuses the git checkout when you have unstaged changes), I would just use git stash as a temporary holding tank.

@matt Unfortunately this doesn't work - the changes seem to be scratched. I'll try popping stashed files from a different commit and report back.

Unfortunately I can't even get to the point of saving the files with git stash, since they contain another git repo which cannot be stashed. I'll use a temporary folder then. Thanks for the tips, through!

I believe the part about the second Git repo is not mentioned in your question.

@matt Okay, I've edited that.

git checkout, git switch, or git stash save as matt suggested should just work. Please edit your question with what happens when you try those commands.

Golden rule of not losing work in git: commit it, and don't be in the habit of force pushing.  You can always rebase and restore as you go as long as you commit your changes.

Do you want to port the local changes that aren't committed ? (<- the goto command is git stash) or port the changes you already committed ? (<- that would be git cherry-pick)

Is what you want to do: "The changes I made should go on a new branch that I want to fork from an older commit"? Or is it more like "I have made some changes that should have been included in an older commit"?

@LeGEC That is indeed what I want to do, but due to the requirement of some of the changes including a nested git repository, not all of these changes can be stashed.

I'll accept the answer below because it works for everything but the nested git repository - for that, I had to stick with using a temporary directory as an intermediary.
